# PDFplumber password and check_extractable

Tags: pdf, pdf-parsing, pdfpages, pdfparser, pdftables

I am using pdfplumber library for parsing pdf. The way to access a pdf file is "pdfplumber.open(path)". Can someone please help me how to pass the password and the check_extractable parameters in this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below syntax for password:

```
pdfplumber.open(path,password="your_password")
```